# Cannot call Request.PhysicalApplicationPath on VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, path

I'm trying to request the path of my application to save new files on it, I know I should do something like this:

```
Dim mypath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

But for some reason I cannot even find the Request class.

[image]

I read it belongs to the System.Web namespace, I added it and still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Server.MapPath("~/logfiles")` to get the path of the subdirectory logfiles in the directory where your web pages are.

Is this in an actual ASP.NET web page, or in a handler?

EDIT

Another way is to use `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "logfiles")`

Comment: @user1676874 It may be that there is no HttpContext at the moment your code is running. A web page is not the same as a web site - what is the name of the file you are having the problem in?